# Python from variable file import

Tags: python

I am new to python i want to use

from **variablefile** import *

i need to take variablefile as a input from user.i tried to use raw_input() but it didn't work,
is there any way in python to do this?

Comment: what is variablefile?

Comment: If you `new to Python` and you are trying to do this: don't. Think about your design, read some examples, and do something different. This is wrong on too many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from ... import *` is not really good practice as it can cause name conflicts and makes it harder to see where classes etc. are really defined. This would especially be the case if you are accepting `...` from the user input

```
import importlib
globals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(variablefile)))
```

Comment: Does importlib offer any advantages over `__import__`?

Comment: I wouldn't import into `globals`, but a variable like `foo = importlib.import_module(variable file))`. At least then you don't have to worry about the module accidentally clobbering other names.

Comment: @grc, it's mentioned in the first paragraph of `help(__import__)`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
myvar = "os"
eval("import %s" % myvar)
```